# ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name=main-nav generates files correctly but they do not run

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I ran a simple command that should generate prebuilt files that would be ready to use as a nav-bar. It downloads correctly but if I add `<main-nav></main-nav>` to my app.component.html page, it will simply output a blank page. There are no errors in my console. The following is the command: `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name=main-nav`
I am using a Mac, Angular 6, and Angular Material. The following is the video that I was following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6qhzG7mObU. I've tested each part independently and have found that the `<mat-sidenav></mat-sidenav>` function does not work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add `MatSidenavModule` to your app's module?

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MatSidenavModule,
    // ...
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, mine was solved by navigating to the main-nav folder that was created after you ran `ng generate @angular/material:material-nav --name=main-nav`

Note: the folder name would be whatever name you assigned --name=?

navigate to `main-nav.component.ts` find the `@components` decorator and find the selector property therein. use that selector as your tag where ever needed like in this case you should replace the  tag in your app.component.html page.

For example, my @components decorator looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-nav',
  templateUrl: './app-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-nav.component.scss']
})
```

So what I would have in my app.component.html page would be `<main-nav></main-nav>`.

I hope this helps someone.